# Linq Intersect bool query and performance

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check if any elements in 2 lists are the same based on a specific property, then just return true, false.

Right now I have:

```
public bool CanEdit(List<RoleType> roles)
{
    var rolesThatCanEdit = new List<RoleType>{
                                   RoleType.Administrator, 
                                   RoleType.Editor
                           };
    //check if the roles can edit.
    return rolesThatCanEdit.Intersect(roles).Any();
}
```

But my guess how this works is that it will make a new list then just check if anything is in the list. Is there a way I can just return true on the first matched element? worst case is there is no matching elements and it will loop through the entire list internally.

Comment: The first line of your question - 'check if any elements in two lists are the same based on a specific property' - doesn't match the code you've provided. You really want to see if any elements in your list are `RoleType.Administrator` or `RoleType.Editor`, correct?

Comment: yes, but I also want to apply it to very large lists which just intersects on certain properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only will it not compute the complete intersection, it will turn the second input list (the one that's not a `this` parameter on the extension method) into a hashtable to enable very fast repeated lookups.  (There may be a performance difference between `rolesThanCanEdit.Intersect(roles)` vs `roles.Intersect(rolesThatCanEdit)`)

Comment: So it depends on which list gets turned into the hash? Any idea which is it? the one passed or the extension one?

Comment: @Lol: It's the second parameter (in your case `roles`) that gets converted to a hash table.  So reversing that would most likely be faster on average (assuming `roles.Count > rolesThatCanEdit.Count`).

Comment: So its better to convert the greater one to hash, that means it will loop over the shorter one?

Comment: @Lol: No, other way around.  Better to loop over the entire shorter one when making the hash, then there's a chance of stopping early on the longer one.

Answer (score 11):

Linq's `Intersect()` method will create and use a `HashTable` for one list internally, then iterate over the other list to see if there is any intersection, then yield those elements that do intersect -  so in Big O terms you have O(m) + O(n) if the full list is iterated over - but iteration will stop after the first yielded element because of the `Any()` operator - still in the worst case (no intersection) this still requires m lookups on the Hashtable each of O(1) so you have O(n) + O(m).

This is pretty efficient (and you cannot do better at least in Big O terms) and certainly trying to do better you would sacrifice a lot readability - until you have proven by measuring that this performance is a problem for you I would go with Linq.

Comment: Your answer is a little more nuanced. On the flipside, I was typing that from my phone.

Comment: Iteration will stop after the first *match*, not the first element tested.  So it isn't `O(n)`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: You have to iterate the full list to build the HashTable - that's O(n)

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Right, and then you have to do a lookup for all non-matching leading elements, that's roughly O(m/n).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes that's right - so worst case you are back to O(n) + O(m) (no intersection)

Comment: @Lol coder: Yes your code should be fine for large sets of data - as @Ben Voigt pointed out the list you pass to `Intersect()` is made a hashset of - you want this list to be the **smaller** one (since you always have to create the full hashset), so I would switch the lists in your example.

Answer (score 0):

It is already optimal: the last chained extension will Early-Out and all the enumerators will get disposed without running to completion

Comment: So internally it will just return true on the first matched element?

Comment: @lol: Intersect returns an Enumerable.  Any calls MoveNext only once, which causes the Enumerable to only search once for a common element.

Answer (score 0):

Use sets (`HashSet<>`) instead of lists and Linq.

Just put all the elements in a set and then iterate the other list and compare.
This is `O(n+m)`.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this instead of using linq? Linq does the same thing but with less typing on the part of the programmer